# If conditions not working according to the way it should - pascal

Tags: loops, if-statement, pascal, freepascal

I did a program in which you type a string and it appends that string to a file. This goes on a repeat loop until the user enters "end". I have declared an if loop. If the variable gets "end" then the loop stops. This happens correctly. The problem is that the word "end" get added to the file as well

```
 x:=0;
  repeat
    writeln('Enter game. Enter "end" to stop');
    readln(game);
    if game <> 'end' then
       x := x + 1 ;
       writeln(filevar,'                ',game);
  until game = 'end'  ;
  close(filevar);
```

Shouldn't the program skip the "If" part as game = 'end' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` scope is wrong.

```
if game <> 'end' then
   x := x + 1 ;
   writeln(filevar,'                ',game);
```

is equivalent to:

```
if game <> 'end' then
begin
   x := x + 1 ;
end
writeln(filevar,'                ',game);
```

You want

```
if game <> 'end' then
begin
   x := x + 1 ;
   writeln(filevar,'                ',game);
end
```